# Jsoup don't parse xml correctly, missing tags

Tags: java, android, xml, jsoup

I want to parse a xml text but jsoup seems to delete `<col>` tags.

This is what happens:

Original:

```
<rowh>      <col>DTC Code</col>     <col>Description</col>  </rowh>
```

Result:

```
<rowh> DTC Code Description 
</rowh>
```

This is the code I am using to see the content.

```
Document jDoc = Jsoup.parse(contentXML);
Log.d("Original", contentXML);
Log.d("Document", jDoc.outerHtml());
```

I need to count how many `<col>` tags are inside each `<rowh>` tag but it always returns 0. I am using Jsoup version 1.11.2

Comment: Solved: Document jDoc = Jsoup.parse(contentXML, "UTF-8", Parser.xmlParser());

Answer (score 1):

May this helps you:

```
String html = "<?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"UTF-8\\\"><rowh><col>DTC Code</col><col>Description</col></rowh></xml>";
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
            Elements e = doc.select("rowh");
            String text = e.text();
            Log.i("TAG1", text);
```

**OutPut:**

[image]

Comment: Please Accept the answer if it is really works for you.